# Ssh users can acces almost any dirs/files

Tags: permissions, ssh, adduser

I'm new to this forum so forgive me if I asked this question in the wrong place, neither could I find a conclusive answer,,

So, I have a dedicated Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, I have it for a while now, it used to be ubuntu 14 sometime and this week I upgraded to 16.04.3.

My question is this, In the past I used to play a bit around with the server, installing things and stuff, getting used to the commandline and playing a bit with chmod and what not.

Recently I became a little more serious, or at least I'm using my server more and I wanted to add another user. But I've found out that if I add another user it can acces almost all directories and files....

Is this because I messed something up in the past (permissions?) or is it normal to actively restrict users? (even though they don't have sudo rights?)

Comment: With "access" do you mean _read_ access? Or also _write_ access? It's quite normal that ordinary users can read almost everywhere but only write in /tmp and their own home directory.

Comment: Yeah that's right, I meant read access. I guess it's my false understanding that a ssh user without sudo would only be able to access his own home folder.. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: For clarification, my new users don't even really need shell/sftp access, it's mainly to provide ssh tunneling and I thought it would be nice to give them also some sftp acces but if it's not possible to restrict them to their home folder I guess I'll restrict shell/sftp totally..